# Phonegap - Can't get Camera to come up at all

Tags: android, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I've read every question both here and on Google and can't for the life of me figure this one out.  I'm simply trying to use Phonegap to take a picture and store the URI.  I'm trying to use the example from the docs [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera).  Here's the snippet where I'm trying to open the camera.

```
this.getPicture = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(self.onBackSuccess, self.onFail, {
      quality: 20,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
};
```

**What I've already checked/verified**

- Phonegap/Cordova itself is installed and working fine.  I can build my app with no problems.
- `navigator.camera` above is definitely defined.  I can follow the code down and the "getPicture" function is being called, but that doesn't pull up the Camera, either on the device, ADB emulator, or Ripple browser emulator.
- Neither my success nor my error callback are ever being called.  However, when I look at those variables in the getPicture function, I can see the appropriate function stored in those variables.
- I have installed the Phonegap camera plugin.  When I run `phonegap local plugin list`, one of the results is `org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera"`
- My config.xml file contains both the lines `<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>` and `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />`.  Not sure if that's relevant, since the plugin is already installed.
- My AndroidManifest.xml file contains the lines `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`, `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`, and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

When I click on the button that calls this function, it prints out this:

```
[20,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,false,false,false,null,0]
```

which is the array of cameraOptions that gets generated/used by the camera.getPicture function.

Everything I've been able to find just takes for granted the fact that calling `navigator.camera.getPicture(success, failure, options);` is going to open the camera, so there doesn't seem to be much info on solving my particular problem.  Any pointers here would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** I am seeing an error in the console that looks like it may be related:

```
Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail.
```

**Edit:** I don't think my last edit is relevant.  That has to do with the loading of the plugin files themselves, and I can see the Camera.js file in the plugins folder when I load my app.  I can put a breakpoint in the cameraExport.getPhoto function and it does go in there.  Then it calls

```
exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Camera", "takePicture", args);
```

which prints out the array I mentioned before and does nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing all of your code, my guess is that the use of `this.` and `self.` is causing the issue. Try something like this:

```
function getPicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onBackSuccess, onFail, {
       quality: 20,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
};

function onBackSuccess() {
   //some code
}

function onFail() {
   //some code
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still call up the camera but just fail when it got to the callbacks though?  Also, I've tried defining the callbacks inline as well to no avail.